# How to convert an input into a regex expression

Tags: python, regex, pandas, input

I'm trying to convert my codes into an open acess. In a certain point i want to ask the other users to put as a input an expression that later is used for str.extract, thus I needed to be a regex expression. I'm using python.

```
def extract_name(x):
    z= input('please enter a string to convert to regex: ')
    regex = re.compile(z)
    #var re = new RegExp(z)
    x['Name']=pd.Series(x['proteins'].str.extract(regex))
    return x
```

This is what i have tried but it dosent work how can I do it?
thanks in advance :)

Comment: How doesn’t it work?  Make a [mcve] with sample input and output and full tracebacks if any.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but here are a few ideas that may help.  You can create a new dataframe column, or edit an existing column, using str.extract.  You need a regex capture group () to extract.  To extract from a dataframe column, skip the pd.Series language and just use the dataframe column.  Here's a toy example:

```
row1list = ['CATG']
row2list = ['CTAG']
df = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list], columns=['proteins'])

df['Name'] = df['proteins'].str.extract('(.A)')
print(df)
#   proteins Name
# 0     CATG   CA
# 1     CTAG   TA
```